# How to add an event in Oxygene?

Tags: c#, .net, oxygene

I want to add a click event to a menu item which is created at runtime.

In Oxygene

```
var mi : MenuItem := new MenuItem();
```

In C# this would have been something like

```
mi.Click += EventHandler(...);
```

However Oxygene does not seem to use the += operator.
[Events](http://wiki.oxygenelanguage.com/en/Events) seem to have been specially treated in Oxygene in a way which is different to C#. What happens when I want to use the original C# event handling so I can use the MenuItem?

Comment: This is a problem which is broader than just menu items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click is an event. So

```
mi.Click += new EventHandler(@Click);
```

Works, or with a lambda:

```
mi.Click += (s, o) -> MessageBox.Show('Clicked the menu!');
```